# WPF visual state transition won't animate

Tags: wpf

I am trying to animate the position of an element using visual states. The problem I have is that, rather than animate, it waits the transition period (0.333 seconds) and pops to the end position. What am I doing wrong?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.UpdateNotificationView" x:Name="UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="UpdatesViewState">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.333">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="NoUpdatesState"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="UpdatesAvailableState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Toast">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border x:Name="Toast" Background="#FFFFFBE9" CornerRadius="0,0,20,0" BorderBrush="#FFFFD100" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="-75"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Grid Margin="15,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="/Namespace;component/Skins/Images/Update.png" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Updates Available" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="29.333"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you called the [`VisualStateManager.GoToState` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991369(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I suspect `KeyTime="0"` might be the concern. try fiddling here. you may perhaps use a simple double animation `<DoubleAnimation To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Toast" />`

Comment: @Sheridan, Yes in my code I do. I guess the animation problem might be a problem in Blend only. It seems to work when I run it.